# How do i get a discord bot to play an mp3 file discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I've only been able to find python versions of this but all i want the bot to do is join a voice channel once an input is made e.g. "%play" and play an mp3 file.

Thanks

Comment: There is a [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) and a [guide](https://discordjs.guide/) for discord.js. There's example of what you are trying to do and even more

Comment: Yeah but its difficult to understand

Answer (score 2):

firstly what JackRed said is correct, there is lots of information for what you want to do. 
Before you ask, have a search on google, you can find lots of tutorials and guides.

If getting the bot to join a voice channel is the problem then have a look [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=join) at the documentation or [this](https://discordjs.guide/voice/the-basics.html#joining-voice-channels). Please note that you need to have discord.js 12 or above to use voice

what you want is something like this:

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content === '%play') {
        // Join the same voice channel of the author of the message
        if (message.member.voice.channel) {
            const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
            // Play audio, see below
        }
    }
});
```

For playing a file, have a look [here](https://discordjs.guide/voice/) at the discord.js guide as it is simple and tells you everything you need to know or more specifically [here](https://discordjs.guide/voice/the-basics.html#playing-audio) as this is exactly what you want. 
what you want is like this,

````js
// when in the voice channel
// Create a dispatcher
const dispatcher = connection.play('audio.mp3');

dispatcher.on('start', () => {
    console.log('audio.mp3 is now playing!');
});

dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
    console.log('audio.mp3 has finished playing!');
});

// Always remember to handle errors 
dispatcher.on('error', console.error);```
````

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying however the discord.js guide doesn't work for me and that's why I asked. and the thing i am struggling with is how to get the bot to join. The picture i answered with shows you

Comment: @Jayeet If you tried code and it doesn't work, then it's not the same kind of answer. here you ask how to do it. Both my comment and this answer give is about how to do it. Now if you tried something and it doesn't work, please  [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60354313/edit) your question by adding code / error so we know what is the problem. We cannot help you without information. Also for the guide, you can change the version from main/stable to v12..

Comment: @Jayeet I have updated my answer, have a look and let me know if this doesn't help